# sqlalchemy table.update.returning only returns one value instead of multiple on postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm using `postgresql` and `sqlalchemy`, here is to update a table and then return multiple values by  using `returning`:

```
async def update_monitor(id: int, payload: MonitorIn) -> Dict[str, Any]:
    
    utc_now = to_utc(datetime.now())
    query = (
        MONITOR
            .update()
            .where(id == MONITOR.c.id)
            .values(**payload.dict(), updated=utc_now)
            .returning(MONITOR.c.id,
                       MONITOR.c.watchlist_id,
                       MONITOR.c.term,
                       MONITOR.c.match_substring_variations,
                       MONITOR.c.nameserver_exclusions,
                       MONITOR.c.text_exclusions,
                       MONITOR.c.created,
                       MONITOR.c.updated)
    )
    result = await PRIMARY.execute(query=query)
    return {'id': result[0],
            'watchlist_id': result[1],
            'term': result[2],
            'match_substring_variations': result[3],
            'nameserver_exclusions': result[4],
            'text_exclusions': result[5],
            'created': result[6],
            'updated': result[7]}
```

`PRIMARY` is a postgresql db.

```
import databases
PRIMARY = databases.Database(config.DB_URL)
```

however, the result is an `int` that corresponds to `MONITOR.c.id` which is the first returned value, so it appears the `returning` method only returns one (the first) value instead of multiple values. I actually hope to get multiple values returned. and according to [this](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/dml.html) it should support multiple values returned. what's wrong here?

Comment: Please define what is `PRIMARY`. What library are you using to wrap SQLAlchemy for async/await? If you get errors, please post the *full traceback*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the [`databases`](https://github.com/encode/databases) library's [`execute()` returns `Cursor.lastrowid`](https://github.com/encode/databases/blob/master/databases/backends/aiopg.py#L149), and if you want the result row(s) [use `fetch_one()` / `fetch_all()` / `iterate()`](https://www.encode.io/databases/database_queries/) instead.

Note that this is **not** the behaviour of SQLAlchemy and `returning()`, as hinted in the title of this question, but of `databases`, which simply uses the SQLAlchemy Core DSL as a way to define queries. Under the hood it then compiles them to text, and uses its own connection pool and the async driver in use to emit the statement to the database.

Comment: you mean result = await PRIMARY.fetch_one(query=query)? I see the result is a <databases.backends.postgres.Record object at 0x10ac63ba8>, how do I get the row record from it?